# Controllers for twitter's structure

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm familiarizing myself with Zend and I'm using Twitter as an example to understand how controllers work.

Twitter has different registration and login pages

`https://twitter.com/login`

`https://twitter.com/signup`

- Would these be 2 different controllers?
- Is there a way to make them 2 actions of the **same controller** while still have them directly at `site/login` and `site/signup`?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the routing technique and/or rewrite rule used on twitter. login and signup could be in the same controller (user/login + user/signup) or compeletely separated.

Have a look at "[the default router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)" to learn about routes. Basically they represent a generic way of pasring an URL into a controller/action scenario.

I'm not that familiar with Zend, but I think you could have login + signup in a single controller if you just write the correct route to handle both URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You need routing in your Zend Application, in your case [Static Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.static).
With routing you can 'tell' where the URL points to.